# debian apache http server throws bad group name nobody error

Tags: linux, apache, shell, security, ssl

I am trying to run an application on debian 8 32 bits OS.
It has an inbuilt httpd server and when i try to start it i get error:

```
httpd: bad group name nobody
httpd/bin/httpd.rc startssl: httpd could not be started
```

Is there any standard way to enable this group (it looks similar to guest user access)
As per the documentation of Debian 8, nobody user is used by processes which do not require any privileges.

Comment: You should file a bug report with Debian. Otherwise, it appears the suffering will continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138972/what-is-the-equivalent-user-for-nobodynobody-from-centos

changed httpd.conf group name from nobody to nogroup

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because the group didnt exist in /etc/group.
I created and it worked